# typescript: не работает ? при работу с типом из нескольких интерфейсов

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-типы

Есть такой код:

```
interface IData1 {
  value: number
}

interface IData2 {
  text: string
}

type IData = IData1 | IData2;

const data1: IData1 = {
    value: 15
}

const data2: IData2 = {
    text: 'data2 test'
}

const data_n: IData = data1;
const data_t: IData = data2;
```

При попытке обратиться к значению, которого нет вылезает ошибка

```
const num: number = data_n.value; // OK, работает
const txt: string = data_t.text;  // OK, работает 
const num2: number | undefined = data_t?.value; // FAILED, Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IData2'.
```

вроде бы при использовании конструкции `?.` если поле отсутствует, то должно вернуться `undefined`

почему этого не происходит и как эту проблему можно исправить?

Comment: Нет, вы неправильно понимаете как работает `?.`

Comment: не спорю, просто я всегда воспринимал конструкцию ?. как получить доступ к члену объекта и если таковой отсутствует, то получить `undefined`, т.е. аналог `obj[key]`

Answer (score 1):

Если я все правильно понимаю, то проблема в том, что такая конструкция `type IData = IData1 | IData2;`, фигурально выражаясь, создает состояние *"суперпозиции"*, когда `IData` одновременно является обоими интерфейсами. Но, как только вы инициализируете переменную, её тип становится детерминированным (либо `IData1`, либо `IData2`).

Т.е., по сути, вот после выполнения этого кода тип переменных становится известен.

```typescript
const data_n: IData = data1; // --> data_n: IData1
const data_t: IData = data2; // --> data_t: IData2
```

Если вам нужно, чтобы тип реализовывал оба инерфейса сразу, а не 1 или 2, то надо вот так делать:

```typescript
type IData = IData1 & IData2;
```

Но у такого варианта тоже есть недостаток, т.к. теперь нужно приводить `data1` и `data2` к новому типу `IData`:

```typescript
const data_n: IData = data1 as IData
const data_t: IData = data2 as IData
```

Дисклеймер: Могу ошибаться. Это чисто мои рассуждения над вашим вопросом.

---

## UPD

к коментарию.

Возможно, что это и правда микроскопом по гвоздям. И я, возможно, тоже немного накрутил... :)

Конкретно для реакта не подскажу, но в целом, возможно стоит воспользоваться Generic'ами. Как-то так:

##### Это, типа, ваши компоненты

```typescript
const component1 = (data: TData<number>) => {
  return data
}

const component2 = (data: TData<string>) => {
  return `text: ${data}`
}


const component3 = (data: TData<IRange>) => {
  return `range: ${data.min} - ${data.max}`
}
```

##### Типы

```typescript
interface IRange {
  min: number;
  max: number;
}

type TComponentTypes = number | string | IRange;

type TData<T> = T
```

##### Обработка массива элементов управления

```typescript
const params: ({ type: string, data: TData<TComponentTypes> })[] = [
  {
    type: "number",
    data: 15 ,
  },
  {
    type: "string",
    data: "data2 test" ,
  },
  {
    type: "range",
    data: { min: 0, max: 100 },
  },
]

params.forEach((param) => {
  switch (param.type) {
    case "number":
      console.log(component1(param.data as TData<number>))
      break
    case "string":
      console.log(component2(param.data as TData<string>))
      break
    case "range":
      console.log(component3(param.data as TData<IRange>))
      break
  }
})
```

#### На случай, если в настройках элементов управления что-то больше чем просто значения:

```typescript
type TData1<T> = {
  name?: string,
  alt?: string,
  //...,
  value: T
}

const componentBig = (data: TData1<number>) => {
  return `${data.name || ""} ${data.alt || ""} ${data.value}`
}

const params1: ({ type: string, data: TData1<TComponentTypes> })[] = [
  {
    type: "number",
    data: { value: 15, name:"asdf" },
  },
  //...,
]
console.log(componentBig(params1[0].data as TData1<number>))
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rame0/9cw8140y/)

Comment: мне как раз нужно именно  - ИЛИ ИЛИ. Опишу ситуацию откуда это возникло, может подскажете решение на уровне архитектуры ибо окажется, что я тут микроскопом гвозди забиваю: У меня есть массив данных, который описывает некоторые элементы управления (реализованные компоненты React), каждый элемент понимает свой тип данных, поэтому для каждого элемента я сделал свой интерфейс, но данные в массиве универсальны вида `{type: string, params: IData}` и имеется в виду что в `params` может быть только или один тип данных или другой, каждый со своими переменными

Comment: например  `{type: 'timeranger', params: {min: '01:00:00', max: '02:30:15'}}` для одного компонента, `{type: 'date', params: {value: '10.02.2023'}}` для другого

Comment: Дополнил ответ, может как то поможет :)